# Taking A Screenshot of the Canvas after WebGL renders primitives

Tags: webgl

I am looking for a method other than the one I found, to display several images, each corresponding to the result of a gl.drawArray(...).
The purpose of the code that follows is to display a web page that explains the fundamentals of webGL

```js
let vertexShaderSource=`
  void main() {
    gl_Position = vec4(0,0, 1, 1);
            gl_PointSize=44.0;
  }
`;
let fragmentShaderSource=`
  precision highp float;
  
  uniform vec4 color;
  void main() {
        gl_FragColor= color;
  }
`;
  
let canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
canvas.style.display="none";
let gl = canvas.getContext("webgl");

let vertex = gl.createShader(gl.VERTEX_SHADER);
gl.shaderSource(vertex, vertexShaderSource);
gl.compileShader(vertex);
let fragment = gl.createShader(gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER);
gl.shaderSource(fragment, fragmentShaderSource);
gl.compileShader(fragment);
const program = gl.createProgram();
gl.attachShader(program,vertex);
gl.attachShader(program,fragment);
gl.linkProgram(program);

gl.useProgram(program);

let ucol = gl.getUniformLocation(program,"color");

gl.uniform4f(ucol,1, 0, 0, 1);
gl.drawArrays(gl.POINTS, 0, 1);

(function () {
    var image = new Image();
    image.onload = function() {
      let div  = document.getElementById("div1");
      div.appendChild(image);
    }
    image.src = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
})();

gl.uniform4f(ucol,0, 1, 0, 1);
gl.drawArrays(gl.POINTS, 0, 1);

(function () {
    var image = new Image();
    image.onload = function() {
      let div  = document.getElementById("div2");
      div.appendChild(image);
    }
    image.src = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
})();
  
gl.uniform4f(ucol,0, 0, 1, 1);
gl.drawArrays(gl.POINTS, 0, 1);

(function () {
    var image = new Image();
    image.onload = function() {
      let div  = document.getElementById("div3");
      div.appendChild(image);
    }
    image.src = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
})();
```

```html
<p>we give the uniform color the value red </p>
<div id="div1"></div>
<p>we give the uniform color the value green</p>

<div id="div2"></div>
<p>.....we give the uniform color the value blue !!!!</p>

<div id="div3"></div>

<canvas  id="canvas"></canvas>
```

you can see that after each gl.drawArray(...) I placed this function:

```
    (function () {
        var image = new Image();
        image.onload = function() {
          let div  = document.getElementById("div2");
          div.appendChild(image);
        }
        image.src = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');

    })();
```

***it is a Self-Executing Anonymous Function,

Is there another way to achieve this result ?***

Comment: Create a non anonymous aka named function that does this and just call it.